# Why react route is not working in material ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, material-ui

I am creating tab and adding routing inside the first tab. But the desired page is not shown after a click on the link. Although after refreshing the page the corresponding page will display on screen. Anyone please help me to solve this where I'm doing wrong im using material UI for this

```
function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <Typography
      component="div"
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      <Box p={3}>{children}</Box>
    </Typography>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
}));

export default function SimpleTabs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
          <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
              <Router>
              <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto"  >

                  <li><Link to={'/Text'} className="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-text-height"></i> Text </Link></li>

                  </ul>
                  <div>

                  </div>
              </Router>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
          <Router>
              <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/Text' component={Text} />

              </Switch>
              </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

so please tell me where should i change or what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you declaring your `Router` component twice? There should be [only one](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router) `Router` component wrapping whole application (not talking about special cases when 2+ are needed) which is the reason your `Link` and your `Route` are not in sync. Try something like this:

```
return (
    <Router>
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
          <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
              <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto"  >

                  <li><Link to={'/Text'} className="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-text-height"></i> Text </Link></li>

                  </ul>
                  <div>

                  </div>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
              <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/Text' component={Text} />

              </Switch>
    </div>
   </Router>
  );
```